# Undo makeFirstResponder

Tags: macos, subclass, nstextfield, nsresponder

I want an `NSTextField` that prevents empty strings so I subclassed the `NSTextField` and implemented this method

```
-(void) textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  if([[self stringValue] isEqualToString:@""])
  {
    NSBeep();
   [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
  }
  else
  {
    //what goes here
  }
}
```

This works when my new text field is the second control in the window but not the first. In those cases I can't tab out of the Subclassed textfield even when its text is non-empty

So, how do I undo the `makeFirstResponder` method? Or is there a way of making the new textfield the **current** responder

Thanks in advance

stupot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're overriding the base function, you should only need to make a call back to the super to make normal behaviour continue.

```
-(void) textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  if([[self stringValue] isEqualToString:@""])
  {
    NSBeep();
   [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
  }
  else
  {
    //what goes here - this:
    [super textDidEndEditing:aNotification];
  }
}
```